# Bounded functions when x tends to infinity

Tags: bounds

Please help me understand the below:

The notation $g(x) = O(f(x))$ denotes that $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|$ is bounded as $x  \to \infty$.
For instance if $g(x)=3x^2 + 2$, then $g(x) = O(x^2)$

So, when the author says bounded, $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is essentially $3 + \frac2{x^2}$ and when $x$ tends to infinity the second part tends to $0$ and hence the boundaries are $[3,0]$??

Note: This is from the book Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning

Comment: You have it reversed: $g = O(f)$ (no "$x$" should appear) means there is a positive constant $M$ for which $|g(x)| \le M |f(x)|$ either for all $x$ or for all $x$ in a neighborhood of an "interesting" argument $x_0.$ Thus, $|g(x)/f(x)|$ is the quantity that must be bounded.

Comment: Thanks a lot @whuber for the correction and explanation!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the absolute value is nonnegative and hence the lower bound of $0$ is not that interesting. The interesting part is on the upper bound.

That is we want to find $C$ such that when $x$ is sufficiently large, we have $$\left| \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right| \le C$$

Since
 $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left| \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right|=\lim_{x \to \infty} 3 + \frac2{x^2}=3.$$

We can find $M>0$ such that $x>M$, then we have $\left| \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right|<4.$

Also, we can also pick the upper bound to be $4$ or any number that is bigger than $3$.

Note that in interval notation, $[a,b]$ means $\{ x: a\le x \le b\}$. $[3,0]$ is widely interpreted as the empty set. It is different from $[0,3]$.

Remark: If the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left| \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right|$ exists, then we know that $g=O(f)$ but the existence of limit is not necessary. For example, we have $sin(x)=O(1)$ as $x\to \infty$ but clearly $\lim_{x \to \infty}|\sin x|$ doesn't exists.